# Python double loop? While and for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, double

I want to loop over a range of c values? How do I do that? I tried having a for loop or a while loop on the outside:

Note: I want c between 4 to 15 with 120 values

```
for c in range(4,15):
    i=0
    while i< nt-1: #if i<nt-1 is true, the body below will be excuted
        #Update the acceleration using the following equation
        x[i+1] = (-y[i]-z[i])*deltat+x[i]
        #Update the velocity using the follwing equation
        y[i+1] =(x[i]+a*y[i])*deltat+y[i]
        #Update the displacement, using follwing equation
        z[i+1] = (b+z[i]*(x[i]-c))*deltat+z[i]
        #go to next time step
        i=i+1
```

OR

```
c=arange(4,15,1)
for p in c:
   while i< nt-1: #if i<nt-1 is true, the body below will be excuted
        #Update the acceleration using the following equation
        x[i+1] = (-y[i]-z[i])*deltat+x[i]
        #Update the velocity using the follwing equation
        y[i+1] =(x[i]+a*y[i])*deltat+y[i]
        #Update the displacement, using follwing equation
        z[i+1] = (b+z[i]*(x[i]-p))*deltat+z[i]
        #go to next time step
        i=i+1
```

Comment: What are the variables `x,y,nt,` and `deltaat`

Comment: The inner loop only runs once because `i` doesn't get reset to zero after it exceeds `nt-1` the first time. But `x`, `y` and `z` are going to be overwritten on each `c` iteration anyway, so I'm not sure you're going to get what you want. How should the result from the different `c` values be combined?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using NumPy, the following is probably the most natural:

```
for c in np.linspace(4, 15, 120):
   ...
```

The [`linspace()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) call produces 120 values:

```
In [33]: np.linspace(4, 15, 120)
Out[33]: 
array([  4.        ,   4.09243697,   4.18487395,   4.27731092,
         4.3697479 ,   4.46218487,   4.55462185,   4.64705882,
         4.7394958 ,   4.83193277,   4.92436975,   5.01680672,
        ...
        14.35294118,  14.44537815,  14.53781513,  14.6302521 ,
        14.72268908,  14.81512605,  14.90756303,  15.        ])
```

Comment: thanks! but it's the while loop is not running through.. I cannot get anything out of this double loop